# MQTT exception in WSO2 products

Tags: mqtt, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using WSO2 APIM (2.5.0) and Analytics snapshot.
I am trying to setup receiver, stream and publisher in APIM. For that, using MQTT event input adapter.

mqtt-client-0.4.0.jar is deployed in all required places of APIM server.

Furthermore, I am now creating the receiver and then tagged that receiver to the Stream and also the publisher has stream attached to it.

Configuration looks fine as the receiver, streams and publisher gets added successfully and there is no error or exception thrown when seen in carbon.logs

Next, when I am subscribing to one of the topic and providing all the relevant information in the receiver for that MQTT topic to get data which is posted every 1 sec from the source dispatcher.
I am getting below exception:

[2019-04-16 10:48:44,937]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.mqtt.internal.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Connection successful
[2019-04-16 10:48:45,813]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.mqtt.internal.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT connection not reachable MqttException (0) - com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Path 'event' not found in the current context:
{"satellites":1,"valid":true,"name":section,"bearing":1.1000,"speed":0,"df":99071508810}
[2019-04-16 10:50:05,905]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.mqtt.internal.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Connection successful
[2019-04-16 10:50:06,921]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.mqtt.internal.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT connection not reachable MqttException (0) - com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Path 'event' not found in the current context:
{"satellites":1,"valid":true,"name":section12,"bearing":1.1789550,"speed":0.9898,"df":71508810}

Also, stream runs but it does not trigger the publisher to post these events through MQTT only or using HTTP adapter.

I am confused that why this exception is coming without any reason. Is it something which is not configured properly for receiver or streams or publisher.

Any thoughts in this direction would be really helpful.

Thanks

I have tried the same setup in Analytics server also as APIM was throwing this error. But this was same in Analuytics server also.